# Remove parts of columns values with regex

Tags: regex, type-conversion, dotted-line

I have a dataframe and in 2 columns i have to change values removing all that is not a number or ".". The final result should be only dotted numbers. thank you very much for those of you can help me. I attach how columns are[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx3o6.png)

Comment: Please, don't post example as image, post text

Comment: Sure, i have a list of 3000 dotted numbers (i.e. 4.31.34) and in few of the I have i.e "4.31.34 and up". what i should do i remove all "and up" and maintain the dotted numbers into the column of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're after is:

```
/[0-9.]+/
```

Explanation:

> `[0-9.]` Looks for one character that is a digit or `.`
>
> `+` repeats last character unlimited times

```js
let regex = /[0-9.]+/;

console.log("1.0.0".match(regex)); //["1.0.0"]

console.log("1.2.4".match(regex)); //["1.2.4"]

console.log("NaN".match(regex)); //[]

console.log("1.1".match(regex)); //["1.1"]

console.log("6.1.61.1".match(regex)); //["6.1.61.1"]

console.log("4.0.3 and up".match(regex)); //["4.0.3"]
```

This will match any combination of numbers and `.` of any character length.

For example:

Comment: Hi chatnoir, thank you for the suggestion. i have a list of 3000 dotted numbers (i.e. 4.31.34) and in few of the I have i.e "4.31.34 and up". what i should do i remove all "and up" and maintain the dotted numbers into the column of the dataframe with an automatic function?

Comment: That regex already "removes" "and up" because those text are neither digits nor `.`. See the last example above "4.0.3 and up" – it only picks up "4.0.3"  (click "Run code snippet").